# How can I see when I last visited a web site to the nearest second?

Tags: firefox

In Firefox one can view one’s history (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) and select the column *Most Recent Visit*, but this only shows the time accurate to one minute. How can I get greater accuracy, exact to at least the nearest second?

I should prefer a solution that works in the browser itself, such as an extension or an `about:config` setting, but would, if that is not possible, also be happy to know how to find it in the profile data.

#### Motivation

In my case I wanted to check this because a site for practising Go – [Guo Juan’s Internet Go School](https://internetgoschool.com/index.vhtml) – may react differently depending on how many seconds one spends on a problem.

#### Other discussions

While trying to find this out I came across a very old (pre Firefox 3) discussion at http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=500060 where someone mentioned an add-on ([#1957](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/1957/)), which evidently no longer exists.

In the Android Stack Exchange, someone asked “[How can I view the timestamp for History items in Firefox Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/201410/how-can-i-view-the-timestamp-for-history-items-in-firefox-android)”, talking of ‘exact times’, but the answer there just refers to the *Most Recent Visit* column as shown by Firefox after syncing your history to a PC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have these possibilities, described below:

- Use an unmonitored Firefox add-on: *easy, limited, use at your own risk*.
- Use SQL to examine Firefox’s database: *powerful, trickier – more suited to power users*.

#### Use the *Better History* add-on

There is an [unmonitored](https://support.mozilla.org/kb/recommended-extensions-program#w_what-are-the-risks-of-installing-non-recommended-extensions) (i.e. ‘use at your own risk’) add-on which does this, called *[Better History](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/firefox-better-history/)*.¹ In its ‘Day View’ this shows times to the nearest seconds, and multiple visits to the same site, unlike the normal history, which only shows the last visit.

An inconvenience is that (as of 2020-06-13) the only way I can find to see the Day view for one year ago is to risk RSI by clicking its <kbd>←</kbd> button 365 or 366 times!

¹ According to a comment below, as of 2024-02-19 one needs a fork of this add-on.

#### Examine timestamps in the profile data

For Firefox 78.0.1 (and presumably many other versions) you can find the timestamps in your Firefox profile data. This gives you a lot more flexibility if you know (or learn) SQL.

The [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) time of the last visit is stored in microseconds from the [UNIX epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) in the column `last_visit_date` in the [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/index.html) database `places.sqlite` in your Firefox profile directory. It may be examined using the [date & time functions](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) of SQLite. It seems that some rows in this table may have a `NULL` value in `last_visit_date`; I do not know what this means.

*I have tested the following instructions with `sqlite3` 3.28.0 (2019-04-16) and `sqliteman` 1.2.2.*

You can examine the timestamps in the following steps:

1. Make sure you have `sqliteman` (GUI) or `sqlite3` (command-line) installed, or an equivalent tool with which you can examine an [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/index.html) database using SQL queries.

   - Perhaps this is in the Firefox installation, but it did not look like it to me.
2. If you do not know where your Firefox profile data is, look this up:

   - https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data#w_how-do-i-find-my-profile.
   - I.e. in Firefox: <kbd>Menu</kbd> – <kbd>Help</kbd> – <kbd>Troubleshooting Information</kbd>, the 8<sup>th</sup> row under **Application Basics**
   - If you do this, you may want to click the <kbd>Open directory</kbd> button to open it in your file manager.
3. Either copy the timestamp data or prepare to access the database in place:

   - To work on a copy, copy the database `places.sqlite` from your profile directory to some location (e.g. a scratch directory or your Desktop).

     - This is possible even if Firefox is active, but you may then **not see all visits** – I observe that they are incomplete and think only the last two or three are missing, but cannot be sure. (Some database systems support copying a database while it is in active use, but I do not think that SQLite does.)
   - If you want to view and even modify the original database:

     1. Only do this if you are **really sure** what you are doing;  **if not, you may corrupt your profile!**
     2. Accessing it in place seems only possible when you are not using Firefox, which presumably excludes other processes from accessing its database, so close Firefox if it is active, as otherwise you will not be able to access the data.
     3. You may want to make a backup copy anyway!
4. Access the copied (or original) database with a GUI **or** command-line:

   - With a GUI:

     1. Open the database with the GUI tool of your choice (e.g. `sqliteman`).
     2. (For `sqliteman`):

        1. The cursor starts in the command area: paste one of the sample queries below or compose your own.
        2. Select the entire command (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>).
        3. Execute the command: <kbd>F9</kbd>.
   - With a command-line:

     - You can issue a single SQL query using `sqlite3` with the syntax `sqlite3 --readonly "_<profile-dir>_/places.sqlite" "_<query>_"`

       - `--readonly` opens the database read-only to prevent accidental updates.
       - `_<profile-dir>_` is your Firefox profile directory.
       - `_<query>_` is the SQL query you wish to execute: see the samples below or compose your own.
     - Alternatively you can access the database with the syntax `sqlite3 --readonly "_<profile-dir>_/places.sqlite"` and issue multiple commands.

Suitable queries are:

- To see all entries with timestamps showing the time to the second in the time zone your computer/session is set up for:

  - `select datetime(last_visit_date/1000/1000,'unixepoch','localtime'), url, title from moz_places where last_visit_date not null`
- Omit `,'localtime'` for times in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) instead of your time zone.
- Omit  `where last_visit_date not null` to include undated entries.
- To see **milliseconds**, use `1000.0` instead of `1000` and `strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f',` instead of `datetime(`, e.g.:

  - `select strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f',last_visit_date/1000.0/1000.0,'unixepoch','localtime'), url, title from moz_places where last_visit_date not null`
- To **sort** by the **time** last visited, with the most recent first, append  `order by last_visit_date desc`, ee.g. (seconds, milliseconds):

  - `select datetime(last_visit_date/1000.0/1000.0,'unixepoch','localtime'), url, title from moz_places where last_visit_date not null order by last_visit_date desc`
  - `select strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f', last_visit_date/1000/1000,'unixepoch','localtime'), url, title from moz_places where last_visit_date not null order by last_visit_date desc`
- To limit to (e.g.) 100 rows, append `limit 100` to the command, e.g.:

  - `select datetime(last_visit_date/1000.0/1000.0,'unixepoch','localtime'), url, title from moz_places where last_visit_date not null order by last_visit_date desc limit 100`
  - **N.B.** SQLite does not accept the syntax `limit to 100 rows` seen in some SQL dialects.
- To restrict to a certain **website**, add `and url like "`*url-prefix*`%"`, ee.g. (for the DuckDuckGo search engine or the site in the original question):

  - `select datetime(last_visit_date/1000/1000,'unixepoch','localtime'), url, title from moz_places where last_visit_date not null and url like "https://duckduckgo.com%" order by last_visit_date desc`
  - `select datetime(last_visit_date/1000/1000,'unixepoch','localtime'), url, title from moz_places where last_visit_date not null and url like "https://internetgoschool.com%" order by last_visit_date desc`

Comment: Search is broken now in "Better History" add-on. "Better History NG" is the forked/updated version: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/better-history-ng/